# Счётный оборот с шахматной фигурой

Tags: синтаксис

Оказывается, слово "ферзь" склоняется как одушевлённое существительное.

Вот счётные обороты:

1) У него на два ферзя больше. (Неодушевлённость)
2) У него на двух ферзей больше. (Одушевлённость)

Мне режет слух выражение "на двух ферзей больше". Поэтому что правильно - вариант 1 или 2?

Вообще, имею я право употребить первый вариант, наделив неодушевлённостью имя ферзь и, соответственно, сделав это слово зависимым родительным падежом единственного числа при главном слове "два" в винительном падеже?

Comment: Страшно представить: на два ферзя больше! :))

Answer (score 2):

Ферзь этимологически произошло от слова "визирь" (советник), поэтому одушевленость у ферзя осталась. В шахматной литературе и непосредственном общении (я кмс и тренер по шахматам) встречал только одушевленный вариант. Сам сказал бы - "у него на двух (пару) ферзей больше".

Comment: Круто! Тогда задам Вам вопрос, Марк, который невольно у меня возник при виде этого вопроса: когда сильные игроки играют, бывают такие ситуации (на двух ферзей больше)? Если да, то насколько они редки?

Comment: Мы играли в шахматы. 100 партий сыграли. Я все проиграл. Но я срубил у него 98 ферзей за эти сто партий. А он у меня срубил все 100. Это всё до мата происходило, лалала. Так вот, стало быть, у него на двух срубленных ферзей (на два срубленных ферзя) активчик больше.

Comment: КМС тебе говорит, а ты ещё не веришь, в скобках другой вариант пишешь!

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой зависит от контроля времени и уровня игроков. Если играется блиц-партия или "пуля" без добавления за ход, то ситуации, где приходится ставить мат двумя  лишними ферзями, бывают нередко. В более длинных контролях хорошоиграющие шахматисты сдаются раньше. Новички всегда играют до мата, поэтому на уровне юношеского разряда позиции с двумя лишними ферзями встречаются регулярно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Марк! Интересно!)

Comment: @МаркИз - ваши примеры несколько натянуты, но есть же такая вещь, как шахматная композиция и особенно - ретроанализ. Там и на девять ферзей больше иметь - не запрещено. Я даже примерно представляю себе позицию, где мат дается единственной пешкой всему этому гарнизону из 9 ферзей при полном комплекте ладей и легких фигур)))

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, если шахматы для вас не совсем уж дремучая область и под рукой или на мониторе найдется доска с фигурами, за подобными ситуациями загляните сюда  http://www.zabaznov.ru/shahmaty /crtk/records.html

Comment: Спасибо, Бегемотус, любопытно!)

Comment: @behemothus https://lichess.org/XsBpuHLCuruE моя последняя партия, где поставил мат, имея на двух ферзей больше. Сыграна менее недели назад.

Comment: А чем на 62-м ходе было плохо защитить пешку королём: h7-g7?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой да, плохо,  я бы тогда мог не успеть поставить мат за оставшиеся у меня 13 секунд.

Comment: @МаркИз вообще-то для простого смертного оборот "на два ферзя больше" означает, что у второго есть хотя бы один.  Ноль против двух - это как-то по-другому. Я это имел в виду говоря о натянутости ваших примеров. А если не секрет, вы с каким контролем эту партию играли? Там на 35-м ходу надо сдаваться было. Я даже не знаю, в теории есть шансы против такого пешечного расклада на ферзевом фланге? Я понимаю, ладейное окончание, но короли вообще где-то гуляют... Две против одной должно выигрываться, не?

Comment: @behemothus 3+0, к 35 ходу у белых выиграно, но я подобные позиции за чёрных даже выигрывал, в блице всё возможно.

Comment: А, пардон... при таком контроле я лучше в минера поиграю. Вопросов не имею.

Comment: Я и не увидел, что у каждого только по три минуты!

Answer (score 2):

Да понятно, что формально правильным будет:  "У него на двух ферзей больше", "У него на двух коней больше". Но звучит - буэээ.

В принципе, грамматика допускает, например, переходы неодушевлённых существительных в одушевлённые, если неодушевлённым именуется живой. Переходы уж если не окончательные, словарные, то по крайней мере контекстуальные.

"Два чайника". Сжёг (что?) два чайника.

"Два чайника" (в значении "два идиота"). "В провале операции я винил этих двух чайников" (людей-идиотов).

Таких примеров можно привести множество, причём не из форумной интернет-писанины, а из серьёзной художественной литературы.

Нет причин для невозможности обратного перехода: конь в значении "фигура" может быть неодушевлённым.

У него на (сколько? что?) на две фигуры больше.
У него на (сколько? что?) на два коня больше.
У него на (сколько? что?) на два ферзя больше.

Answer (score 2):

Оба варианта возможны и равнозначны, хотя одушевленный, судя по всему, предпочтителен. Об относительной употребительности того и другого судить не берусь. И даже не по причине диковатости самой ситуации (в задачках на ретроанализ и не такое бывает), а просто по причине методических трудностей подобных подсчетов.

По пунктам.
1. "Ферзь" действительно слово грамматически одушевленное. Хотя возведение его к визирю встречает возражения, этимология не является определяющей для грамматической одушевленности. На одушевленность ферзя есть прямые указания в ряде источников.

> Грамматическая категория одушевленности проявляется и при склонении
>   названий шахматных фигур, карт, например: взять ферзя; - Ох, эта
>   пешка! - вскричал Сергей Филиппович... - Нельзя вывести коня, ладья
>   стоит без дела (Загоскин); Муся играла в карты нехотя, равнодушно,
>   путая королей с валетами (Добровольский); Он положил козырного туза и
>   улыбнулся: - Тридцать четыре очка - одна взятка (Вс. Ив.).

Валгина
http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-057.htm

2. Проявление грамматической одушевленности сочетания существительного с числительным не до конца определяется одушевленностью самого существительного. "В нашем отделе на двух инженеров больше" или "...на два инженера" - форма может определяться контекстом, хотя вторая носит разговорный характер. В случае же со составными числительными "неодушевленная" форма - единственно возможная.

См. Розенталь, $153 
https://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/1015483/193/Rozental_-_Spravochnik_po_pravopisaniyu%2C_proiznosheniyu%2C_literaturnomu_redaktirovaniyu.html

3. При всем том одушевленность "ферзя" ограничена случаями, не несущими собирательного значения. Конструкции типа "двоих ферзей" (как "двоих братьев") совершенно невозможны.
4. В остальном причин сомневаться в одушевленности ферзя не приходится. Формы типа **"[разменяли] двух ферзей"** безусловно предпочтительнее, чем "...два ферзя", но последнее исключить до конца не могу.
5. Этот случай общий, его нельзя сводить к профессионализмам типа бильярдного "загнал шара".
6. В отношении одушевленности другого шахматного материала, видимо, можно сказать примерно то же самое, хотя одушевленность "пешки" и особенно "ладьи" часто оспаривается.

Answer (score 0):

Рискну ответить. Выскажу своё мнение.

(Вообще, насколько я знаю, правильно считать фигуры неодушевлёнными, то есть правильно:
*У него на дв**а** ферз**я** больше.*)

Теперь Марк сказал, что ферзя тоже одушевляют, поверим ему. Вариант в скобках отпадает.

То же с ***пешками, ладьями.*** Но когда речь заходит о ***конях и слонах***, естественно придать им одушевлённости, поскольку есть такие животные. Для меня странно обращаться с шахматными фигурами иначе, чем с животными.

С ***королём*** бы поступил так же, как и с последними, да не приходит в голову примера, который бы обнаружил его одушевлённость.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд (просто кандидата), в случае шахматных фигур условная одушевлённость не имеет *универсального* значения. Она проявляется в контексте:

> Он разменял двух/обоих (своих) *ферз**ей*** (слонов, коней; ср. [две/обе
>   свои] ладьи).

Но если акцент делается на *счёте*, то одушевлённая сущность становится отвлечённой **единицей измерения**:

> [Фигур] у него *на два ферз**я*** (слона, коня, человека, директора)
>   больше.

(подобно тому, как "/подчинённых/ у него *на два человека* больше")

Comment: Ну я про это и сказал: переход в контексте одушевлённого сущ. в неодушевлённое - в сочетании с числительным.